# PHP: Is this "Undefined variable" exception a scope issue with my static method?

Tags: php, scope, static-methods

I have a static function which gets a few variables defined prior to going into a `foreach()` loop.
From within the `foreach()`, I try to call my `$pnUuid` var, and get

> **Unhandled Exception**   Undefined variable: pnUuid

I can successfully echo the var *prior* to the loop, as well as from *within* the loop if I immediately follow that print with `die()` or `continue`.
Calling `global $pnUuid` also circumvents the exception, but then the var is ***NULL*** :(

```
public static function find( $input ) 
{
    // instantiate
    $resultsByBrand = array();
    $brandDictionary = new BrandHashTable();

    // attempt to get a PN UUID
    $partnumber = PartNumberEntity::where( 'number', '=', $input['partnumber'] )->first();
    $pnUuid = empty($partnumber) ?  false : $partnumber->uuid;

    // get current inventory for the PN
    $rzStocklines = RzStockEntity::where('fullpartnumber', '=', $input['partnumber'])
            ->get( array('fullpartnumber', 'manufacturer', 'quantity'));

    // process the stocklines
    foreach( $rzStocklines AS $row )
    {
        // do our darndest to get a UUID for the Brand
        $brandDictionary->registerByName($row->manufacturer);
        $brandUuid = $brandDictionary->getUuid($row->manufacturer);

        // set a key of either the brand name, or the uuid
        $key = $brandUuid ?  $brandUuid : $row->manufacturer;

        // instantiate the object for this brands results
        if( !array_key_exists($key, $resultsByBrand))
        {
            $resultsByBrand[$key] = new stdClass();
            $resultsByBrand[$key]->partnumber = $row->fullpartnumber;
            $resultsByBrand[$key]->brand = $row->manufacturer;
            $resultsByBrand[$key]->quantity = 0;
            $resultsByBrand[$key]->minimum_order_quantity = 1;
        }

        // include the qty with the total sum
        $resultsByBrand[$key]->quantity += $row->quantity;

        // make sure we need Product-level info before doing the work to get it
        if( !isset( $resultsByBrand[$key]->grams_piece_weight ))
        {

//echo '<pre>Brand UUID:<br />',print_r($brandUuid, TRUE),'</pre>';  // For Testing ----->
//echo '<pre>PN UUID:<br />',print_r($pnUuid, TRUE),'</pre>';  // For Testing ----->
//die('(Dead by request)');  // For Testing ----->
/**
 * This is a _**wierd**_ one ... 
 * An "Undefined Variable: $pnUuid" exception is getting thrown.
 * If we call "die()" or "continue()", it goes away.
 * Casting it as a global also works, but then it is NULL
 */
global $pnUuid;  // hackity hack hack hack

            // check for product-level info
            if( $brandUuid && $pnUuid )
            {
                $product = ProductEntity::where(
                                function ($query) use ($brandUuid, $pnUuid) {
                                    $query->where('partnumber_uuid', '=', $pnUuid);
                                    $query->where('company_uuid_brand', '=', $brandUuid);
                                })
                            ->first();

                // add product-level info to $resultsByBrand[$key]
                if( !empty( $product ))
                     $resultsByBrand[$key]->grams_piece_weight = $product->piece_weight;

            }   //if( $brandUuid && $pnUuid...
        }   //if( !property_exists...

        unset( $brandUuid, $pnUuid );

    }   //foreach( $rzStocklines AS...

    return $resultsByBrand;

}
```

What the heck is going on here ???

BTW, I also just tried it as a non-static method, and it still throws the same exception.

Comment: Where exactly is the exception being thrown? I'm guessing in the `ProductEntity::where` section?

Comment: Oh yeah ... that might be helpfult to know, huh? :)  It's getting thrown at `if( $brandUuid && $pnUuid )` ... just before `ProductEntity::where`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's probably not defined in the *second loop iteration* because you're `unset`ting the variable in the loop...?!